# Workaround advice for "Too many SOQL queries"

Tags: apex, soql, bulkification

We are a vacation rental management company with **70** properties. I am trying to write a schedulable apex class that will scan through each Property__c to retrieve the next arriving Account (**70** queries) and the in-House Account (**70** queries)

This means that I need to perform 140 queries in order to gain the relevant information. Obviously that is not possible due to the governor limits. Could anyone offer a work-around to my current code?

```
    for (Property__c property : [SELECT Name, Id, Onboarding_Status__c, Next_Arrival__c, In_House_Account__c, Is_Clean__c, Late_Check_Out__c 
                                             FROM Property__c WHERE Onboarding_Status__c = 'Online'])
    {          
        Account nextArrival = nssUtil.nextArrival(property);
        Account inHouseAccount = nssUtil.accountInhouse(property);
    }
```

> nssUtil.nextArrival - Uses SOQL to locate the next arriving Account
>
> nssUtil.inHouseAccount - Uses SOQL to locate the inHouse Account

```
//Returns the next account to arrive at a property, If none exist, returns null.
    public static Account nextArrival(Property__c property)
    {
        try
        {
            Account account = [SELECT Id, Name, Arrival_Time__c, Property__c, Property__r.Name FROM Account 
                               WHERE Arrival_Time__c >= :Datetime.Now() AND Property__c = :property.Id ORDER BY Arrival_Time__c ASC LIMIT 1];
            return account;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The best option here is to use collections for your code. It would be great if you can post your nssUtil.nextArrival and nssUtil.accountInhouse code in your question so that we can give you better suggestion.

Comment: @Himanshu Will do! I will just post nssUtil.nextArrival. They are very similar methods.

Comment: what is the relationship between Account and Property__c. lookup or master detail ?

Comment: The Account has a Property__c lookup relationship @Himanshu

Answer (score 3):

```
//Query initial data to prepare map of items.
Map<id,Property__c> mapProperty = new Map<id,Property__c>([SELECT Name, Id,
Onboarding_Status__c, Next_Arrival__c, In_House_Account__c, Is_Clean__c, 
Late_Check_Out__c FROM Property__c WHERE Onboarding_Status__c = 'Online'])

//this Map will hold your data for every property and one latest account.
Map<id,Account> mapPropertyAccount = new Map<id,Account>();

//query the Account data and iterate over it for all properties.
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, Arrival_Time__c, Property__c,
Property__r.Name FROM Account WHERE Arrival_Time__c >= :Datetime.Now() AND Property__c in :mapProperty ORDER BY Arrival_Time__c ASC])
{
  //if not exist in map add that into map
  if(!mapPropertyAccount.containskey(acc.property__c))
  {
     mapPropertyAccount.put(acc.property__c,acc); 
  }
  else
  {
     //if already exist compare the value and if new value is new from the 
     map replace the map value
     if(acc.Arrival_Time__c>  
     mapPropertyAccount.get(acc.property__c).Arrival_time__c)
    {
       mapPropertyAccount.put(acc.property__c,acc); 
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have complete visibility of your code but what I understood this code should achieve that. at the end you will have a map **mapPropertyAccount** which will contains a single Account per Property__c which you can use in your logic. it will fire only 2 SOQL in whole transection instead of 140.

Comment: @AlexBrigham extra tip -- use a Util class to fetch `now` ; said `Util.getNow()` and `Util.setNow(DateTime somedt)` can be used to assign different values of `now` in testmethods against your mocked test data; for PROD, `Util.getNow()` always returns `system.now()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has been great guidance. The account SOQL query does not work however because it fetches several accounts for each property. What I need in a SOQL query is to say: LIMIT 1 Account record PER Property record. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use Maps in your code and use that map in for loop.
You should write a single query that will have all list of accounts that you need except `LIMIT 1` now use this list of account to get next arriving Account.

Same with inHouse Account.

And if you don't want to do this, you can use **batch**, as Asynchronous process has 200 SOQL limit in a single request.